# Why P-Ch FETs values are in negative?

Tags: batteries, battery-charging, bms

I have a doubt about why the P-Channel FET values in the [datasheet](https://aosmd.com/res/data_sheets/AO3401A.pdf) are negative:
[image]

The reason why I am asking about this FETs is that I am drawing the schematic for a Battery Management System based on [BQ76920](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/bq76920.pdf?ts=1678426793611&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fproduct%252FBQ76920) and the P-Channel FET Q3 is used to keep CHG terminal away from any voltages below VSS according to the datasheet:

[image]

I am drawing the schematic based on this [github project](https://github.com/ceech/BQ76920-BMS/blob/master/Schematic_01.png) for guidance but the schematic says (Q4: 30 V, 2.5 A)

Could I use the AO3401A P-CH FET I listed above? (considering the Vds=-30V and Id=-4.0A)

[image]

Comment: Why so you have a doubt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FET parameters are referenced to the source/body terminal. In a p-FET the source/body is connected to a more-positive voltage while in the n-FET it's connected to a more-negative voltage.

For the p-FET to do anything useful, it needs to see gate and drain voltages **lower** (more negative) than the source, compared to the n-FET where these biases are **higher** (more positive). The datasheet polarity reflects this fact. (Nevermind that it's possible to have FET drain current in either direction. The datasheet specs here are for the FET operating in 'normal' forward mode, which it is for Q3 in the schematic.)

For example, threshold voltage Vgs for a logic FET might be:

- n-channel: gate to source threshold, Vgs(th), 2.5V
- p-channel: gate to source threshold, Vgs(th), -2.5V

Same for Vds, Id:

- n-channel: drain to source max, Vds(max), 30V
- p-channel: drain to source max, Vds(max), -30V
- n-channel: drain to source current max, Id(max), 2.5A
- p-channel: drain to source current max, Id(max), -2.5A

Bipolar transistors are similar in the NPN and PNP opposite symmetries. Compare for example 2N3904 vs. its PNP complement 2N3906. Similar, but opposite.

As for the drawing, yes, that part will work even though they didn't list (-) values for Vds and Id.

That is, they meant to specify the FET as:

- Vgs (max) -30V
- Id (max) -2.5A

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed explanation, so with reference to the values, could I use the AO3401A P-CH FET I listed above? (considering the Vds=-30V and Id=-4.0A) for my requirement of 30 V, 2.5 A ??? thanks a lot!

Comment: Yes, it’s fine.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

It depends on your reference point. Generally the source is also the reference point, many people mistakenly assume ground is the reference point. The source is also the reference point when looking at the data sheets. When turning on a MOSFET the voltage is stated as Vgs (Voltage gate source) hence the source is the reference. For N-Channel MOSFETs you need to have gate voltage at least Vgs or greater to turn on, the same also applies to P-Channel MOSFETs. The only obvious difference is the polarity although they are not the same internally.